# AWK errror "unterminated regexp" and "unexpected newline or end of string"

Tags: bash, awk

in a bash script I'm doing the following cmds:

```
NO_VALUE_percentage=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($NO_VALUE/$map_total_pixel_value)*100}")
SNOW_VALUE_percentage=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($SNOW_VALUE/$map_total_pixel_value)*100}")
CLOUD_VALUE_percentage=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($CLOUD_VALUE/$map_total_pixel_value)*100}")
```

if I call this cmds in a bash script I get no errors but when I call this script from another code I get the following errors:

```
ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ unterminated regexp
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ unterminated regexp
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ unterminated regexp
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN {print (/483000)*100}
TRACE - ERROR>awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

could you please help me in fix this problem? Is it related with quotes?

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment, but a bunch of guessing here)

I assume your NO_VALUE and other variables are local to your calling script.

When you call thisone, those vars are not in environment and your script has no idea of their values and as such the command become `print "/48300.."` which awk can't interpret properly.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong way to use the value of shell variables in an awk script:

```
NO_VALUE_percentage=$(awk "BEGIN {print ($NO_VALUE/$map_total_pixel_value)*100}")
```

Right way (and added divide-by-zero protection):

```
NO_VALUE_percentage=$(awk -v noval="$NO_VALUE" -v mpval="$map_total_pixel_value" 'BEGIN {print (mpval ? (noval/mpval)*100 : 0)}')
```

That doesn't mean your code will work after making those changes but it will avoid the cryptic error messages that your currently getting because you're letting shell variables expand to become part of the body of the awk script before awk even sees it. Hopefully whatever problems you have afterwards will be obvious and easy for you to fix.